# how to validate UserName claim in Jwt token Authentication owin middleware

Tags: c#, jwt, owin

I'm using `JwtBearerAuthentication` `middleware`  for authenticating incoming requests:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidateIssuer"].ToString();
            var secretkey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecretKey"].ToString();


            var jwtAuthOption = new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                TokenHandler = new JwtTokenBearerHandler(),
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {                   
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = issuer, //some string, normally web url,  
                    ValidAudience = issuer,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretkey))
                }
            };
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(jwtAuthOption);
//Other Middlewares
}
```

Beside all of validation while authentication in this middleware, i also need to get username that stored as a `ClaimTypes.Name` in claims and check if it is really a valid username or not, what is the best approach?

Comment: How do you define "valid username"? Not null? Is an email address? Something else?

Comment: I just check it from database.